# How to restrict access to web application by user other than IP based filtering?

Tags: jsp, servlets, web, web-applications

I have a web application(JAVA/JSP) which serves requests from users. We also provide interface/adapter(JAVA/JSP/php/perl...) to users to connect to our web application. For security reasons we also give a UID and public key to each user after registration with us so that our users can start sending requests to our web application.

Now the users are replicating our key and interface/adapter and using it to send requests from new users without registering with us.

How can we restrict the access in this scenario so that we can identify the duplicate requests? We cannot use IP based restriction because all the duplicate requests are coming from the same IP and it was found in our internal audit and IP based validation already exists in our code and its getting by passed in this scenario.

Comment: UID is for users or interface?? if the UID is for interface, validate the users with their email, check their email is registered with you before giving access. IF the UID is for users, then i think there is no chance for duplicate

Comment: The UID is for users. The users say super users are creating sub users with the same UID and key and sending requests from the same domain. If we use email id based validation also they will use the same email id for the sub users as well

Comment: Create a service that generates a new one time key. This service can be accessed by users by logging in with their registered account. Expire the key after a certain time or on access.